# Why does my attempt to print the index of my array ALWAYS return 0.00?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

This is the section of code I am talking about. I have ensured all braces are accurate. At the end I have two other print statements to prove that the correct values ARE in the array, but when I use System.out.printf to try and print the entire index, it just returns 0.00. I have printed indexes with System.out.print(array[i]); before, and it worked fine. Other types of print commands besides the one with the format command also return 0.00. I'm learning Java and this is making me pull my hair out. Thank you.

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
int numVals;
int i;
double maxDouble;
double[] myVals = new double[20];
numVals = scnr.nextInt();
for (i=0; i < numVals; ++i) {
    myVals[i] = scnr.nextDouble();
}
  
maxDouble = myVals[0];
for (i=0; i<numVals; ++i) {
      if (maxDouble < myVals[i]) {
          maxDouble = myVals[i];
      }
}
System.out.println(maxDouble); // THIS CORRECTLY RETURNS MAXDOUBLE
System.out.println(myVals[2]); // THIS CORRECTLY RETURNS DATA FROM [2] 
System.out.printf("%.2f", myVals[i]); //THIS ALWAYS RESULTS IN 0.00
System.out.println(myVals[i]); //THIS ALSO RETURNS 0
```

Multiple print commands, proving the values are in the array and initialized correctly, rewriting and formatting print command.

Comment: Because after the loop `i` is one more than `numVals` and you're reading past the values you put into the array. Just for fun, make `numVals` exactly 20 (or make `double[] myVals = new double[numVals]` after you've decided the value for `numVals`) and see what happens.

Comment: You're accessing through `i` which is out of your boundary set via numVals, due to the for-loop incrementation afterwards. So if your numVals is 5, `i` therefore is 5, which's index of myVals is pointing to 0.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca don't scare him away ;)

Comment: There is no problem to solve here. Basic tip: Never use a loop variable outside the loop. Better tip: declare the loop variable in the loop: `for (int i=0; i<numVals; ++i) {` and you won't be *able* to use it outside the loop.